# Find the last modified files with different file names in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder full of SQL backups from different DBs. I need to isolate the last modified from each DB and delete the rest.

I can find the last modified of them all and delete the rest but that would delete the last backup from the other 2 DBs.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse |
         Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer}
$keep = 1
if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
    $files | Sort-Object CreationTime |
        Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) |
        Remove-Item -Force
}
```

This will just Keep the newest and remove the rest.

So if I have

```
db1.bak
db1.bak
db1.bak
db2.bak
db2.bak
db2.bak
db3.bak
db3.bak
db3.bak
```

how do I keep the last modified of each then delete the rest?

Comment: Gci -filter db1 . Or a hashset @{} and add with a try catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the files by name, skip the most recent file from each group, and remove the rest.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse |
    Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer}
    Group-Object Name |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group |
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Desc |
            Select-Object -Skip 1 |
            Remove-Item -Force
    }
```

Comment: Sorry should have made my self more clear, an example of the files names are :- pr02_backup_enr_20190515_12256.bak , pr02_backup_enr_20190515_125256.bak, rnk_pr02_gro_20190515_1017.bak, rnk_pr02_backup_leo_backup_20190516_16129.bak. so i think i need to wildcard the names first.

Comment: @DONALDO Yes, you should have. Anyway, you can use a scriptblock argument instead of a property name with `Group-Object`, e.g. something like `Group-Object { $_.Name.Substring(0,5) }`.